# nodejs writes a program that executes a call to an HTTP endpoint at a specified time

Tags: node.js, httprequest, http-response-codes

### Summary

I'm creating a program to send a request to the HTTP endpoint as follows.

1. send a HTTP request by POST
2. receive response data
3. HTTP request by PUT at the ID and time received by POST during POST response.
4. receive response data

### code

A nodejs in the making

```
'use strict'

const http = require('http');
const HOST = `hoge.io`;
const PATH = `/path`;

let postData = {
  "name": "stack",
};

let postDataStr = JSON.stringify(postData);
let options = {
    host: HOST,
    port: 80,
    path: PATH,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postDataStr)
    }
};

let req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  let data = '';
  let body = '';
  console.log(`POST statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
    let resultData = '';
      data = JSON.parse(body);
      let now = new Date().getTime();
      let time = data.actives_at - now;
      // setTimeout(putData.bind(this, data), time);
      console.log(data)
  });
});
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log('error: ' + e.message);
});
req.write(postDataStr);
req.end();
```

### response value

```sh
node api.js
{
  id: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  actives_at: xxxxxxxxxx (in UNIX time milliseconds),
  called_at: xxxxxxxxxx,
}
```

### What I want to do.

When this reaches the time of actsives_at, we want to send the request to the endpoint with a PUT as shown below.

```sh
$ curl -X 'PUT' -H 'X-Id:xxxxxxxxxx' http://hoge.io/path
```

What additions to the code would I need to make to make this happen?

Comment: I would suggest using the [`got()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) for making your GET and PUT calls as it's a higher level library and it supports promises which makes sequencing things simpler.  You can use `setTimeout()` to schedule when the PUT runs.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00. But If possible, I would like to achieve this without the use of libraries.

Comment: Why not use libraries?  To me 80% of the reason to program in node.js is so you can use the vast library of tested, open source code in NPM.  It allows me to do my job many, many times faster than writing all the code myself and I end with far fewer bugs and I can concentrate on the things that really matter to my app rather than just the mechanics of doing things like http requests.  Sure, you can program it yourself, but it takes more code, more learning and more opportunities for mistakes or bugs.  FYI, you can always code it yourself without libraries.  The question is should you?

Comment: Hi @jfriend00.This is because I learned about http requests through building an app.

Comment: I have no idea what that last comment means.  I suggested an easier way to get your task accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using AgendaJS (https://github.com/agenda/agenda), a scheduler using Mongodb to store your data.
It will accept a Date object or a timestamp or even a MomentJS object and will run a function you define when the time come